# jQuery .css() not working in FF, but does work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using Backbone and have the following view:

```
class GT.RunManager.Views.ViolationMarker extends Backbone.View
 className: 'violation-marker'

 template: JST['app/templates/violation_marker']

 initialize: (@options) ->
   @x = @options.x
   @y = @options.y
   @location = @options.location
   @render()

 render: =>
   @$el.html @template()
   @$el.data 'location', @location
   @$el.css
     'top': @y
     'left': @x
   this
```

Which is called from:

```
class GT.RunManager.Views.FloorplanView extends Backbone.View
  className: 'floorplan-view'

  events:
   'click .violation-marker' : 'edit_location'
   'click'  : 'create_location'

 initialize: (@options) ->
   @run = @options.run
   @student = @options.student
   @floorplan = @options.run.get('floorplan')
   @locations = new GT.RunManager.Collections.Locations()
   @locations.run = @options.run
   @locations.on 'add', @set_marker
   @locations.on 'reset', @load_markers

 @run.on 'remove_location', (location) =>
   location.destroy() if location
   @load_markers()

 @locations.fetch data: { student_id: @student.id }
 @render()

render: =>
  if @floorplan
    @$el.css 'background-image', "url(data:image/png;base64,#{@floorplan.url})"
  this    

create_location: (e) =>
  @locations.create x: e.offsetX - 10, y: e.offsetY - 10, student_id: @student.id, run_id: @run.id

load_markers: =>
  @$el.find('i').remove()
  @locations.each (location) => @set_marker(location, false)

set_marker: (location, prompt = true) =>
  marker = new GT.RunManager.Views.ViolationMarker(location: location, x: location.get('x'), y: location.get('y'))
  @$el.append marker.el
  if prompt
    @run.trigger 'violations:set', location
```

The idea is to position an icon on the screen where the user touched it (on an iPad, for exp). It works great in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox, in which the icon is instead placed in the top left corner of the parent div.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This backbone view is styled with the following css:

```
div.violation-marker {
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
@include border-radius(6px);
padding: 4px;}
```

The template is just (bootstrap):

```
<i class="icon icon-fire icon-white"></i>
```

And the parent div is styled with:

```
.floorplan-view {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 100px;
width: 755px;
height: 755px; }
```

Comment: What other CSS applies to `@el` and its parent element?

Comment: That's the only css applied to @el. It has a class with css `div.violation-marker {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  @include border-radius(6px);
  padding: 4px;
 }`

Comment: What about the parent? Is the parent `position: relative`? No size on `.violation-marker`?

Comment: edited my original question to answer your questions.

Comment: Don't you have to separate the css values by comma? @$el.css 'top': @y, 'left': @x sometimes is as simple as that.

Comment: @MichaelD.Irizarry: CoffeeScript can infer the commas in this case.

Comment: That should work fine, what are you doing that is different from http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DfKqg/ (which works the same in Safari, Chrome, and FireFox)?

Comment: @muistooshort I added the rest of the view code above - it looks pretty similar to your jsfiddle.  Anything stand out to you?

Comment: added the calling view above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that Firefox does not handle e.offsetX and e.offsetY. As soon as I changed the way I captured the location everything worked fine.  Here is the Firefox-proof version of grabbing the x-coord:

`x = (ev.offsetX || ev.clientX - $(ev.target).offset().left)`

Thanks for all the help.